# Python: Transforming column of data into spreadsheet

Tags: python, csv, text

I am a statistician and am somewhat new to Python.  I have a text document that looks like:

**Arrest #** 1
**Arrest Date**
01/08/2011
**Sex**
Male
**Charge**
Assault

**Arrest #** 2
**Arrest Date**
01/13/2011
**Sex**
**Charge**
Deviant
Trespassing

**Arrest # 3....**

I would like to transform this into the following form:

**Arrest   Sex           Charge**
1                 Male              Assault
2                 Missing      
Deviant Trespassing
3...

I can pull out the text in between say Arrest Date and Sex using regular expressions, but I cannot figure out how to perform these operations for each arrest.  This is a problem that I encounter a lot as police departments tend to hand over PDFs (which I then convert into tex files that are in the above format), and not spreadsheets, and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Comment: `> police departments tend to hand over PDFs, and not spreadsheets` you're asking if python can run regex over a PDF? I don't think so. Not the way you expect, anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my question.  The original PDFs look nothing like a spreadsheet, which I think is intentional.  When I convert the PDFs into the text document I get one long column of data in my text editor.  I think this is quite common, in my humble opinion, among those who of us like myself who request a lot of data from government agencies and Python code explaining how to transform a column of data into a spreadsheet I think would be quite broadly useful.

Answer (score 0):

1) use regex.findall or split() command to break original data into a list.

2) loop through your list and take out the important information, put it into a dictionary, and append it to a list.  (you want a list of lists of dictionaries, [{"Arrest":  1, "date": 01/08/2011, "sex": "male", "charge":"assault"}, {}, {}...]

3) open up a txt file and writerows, big_list[0]{'arrest'}, big_list[0]{'date'}, etc